# What devices support a 15mm tall 2.5" hdd?

Tags: laptop, hard-disk

I've bought [THIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZMUNGR) hard drive for my laptop but didn't notice it as 15mm. I've never seen a laptop that supports a HDD this thick. I've searched in some forums with no success. Is there any recent gaming laptop that fits?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You want to buy a new laptop, in addition to your current one, for your 130 dollar hard drive? If that *is* what you want, it might be tricky to find a modern laptop that supports it. Have you considered an external hard drive, or getting a 2 TB HDD for your current laptop? Or, if you'd be willing to buy a 1000 dollar laptop for your hard drive, maybe buy a 4 TB Samsung SSD instead that'll fit in a laptop.

Comment: I already have a 2Tb HDD in my laptop, but it is a 2012 Lenovo Y580. Though it is really good, I'm also considering buying a new laptop (maybe an ASUS Rog) and I would eventually transfer the 4Tb HDD to the new Laptop. Now, I can't use it in my current Laptop, but I hope to be able to use it on my future one.

Comment: That drive probably isn't designed for laptops, as very few are that thick. Normally 2.5" drives that thick are designed for servers, but the fact that it's a Barracuda drive and not a NAS/enterprise level drive makes me wonder who this product is intended for.